# Convert a char to upper case using regular expressions (EditPad Pro)

Tags: regex

I wrote a regular expression in hope that I will be able to replace every match (that is just one char) to upper case char. I am using EditPad Pro (however I am willing to use any other tool that would allow me to do this, as long as it is free to try, since I only need to do this once).

**Background:** I have a very long text file used by a case sensitive application, and some words start with lower case instead of upper case char, thus crashing the application. This would take very long to do by hand, and it would be quite complicated to do without regular expressions because the occurrence of the (evil) lower case char is very specific.

I have written the select regular expression and now I can use it with a backreference ($1 works just fine) however I can't make it replace with upper case char. I thought something like \u$1 would work, however it doesn't in EditPad Pro.

If no free tool allows me to do this, I guess the alternative would be to just do it in C# however I am in a bit of a hurry and not near a compiler, so I'd have to download the express edition first, so ... It would be preferable to find a tool that supports such a feature!

Thank you!

Comment: Is this question more suited to Superuser?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

TextPad will allow you to perform this operation.

example:

```
test this sentence
```

Find what: `\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)`
Replace with: `\U\1\E \2`

the `\U` will cause all following chars to be upper

the `\E` will turn off the `\U`

the result will be:

```
TEST this sentence
```

Comment: Is there a way to perform this operation in .NET Regex (without using `ToUpper`)?

Comment: Works in notepad++ as well.

Comment: `\U$1\E` in _Sublime Text_

Comment: U\1\E in Ultraedit, tested in version 20, regex as PERL

Comment: In Notepad++ find should be `(.*)` and replace should be `\U$1`

Comment: Does not work in Eclipse (tested with Luna and Mars) :-(

Comment: Works in PHPStorm too. I had the opposite requirement though. I had to replace all uppercase attribute values (from probably '90s HTML) to lower case. Using `\L$1\E` worked.

Comment: Works in GEdit 3.10.4 via Ctrl + H

Comment: I would like to know where to consult all \A \B \C ..  uses and meaning in regex, any link?

Comment: Just for the record example for shell command: `$ echo 'test this sentence' | sed -r 's|([^ ]*) (.*)|\U\1\E \2|'`

Comment: Works in Kate as well: \U\1\E

Comment: Works in R as well: `gsub(pattern, replace = "\\U\\1", x, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: And this is how you do it in VIM.
`:s/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g`
I apply this on visual selection.
Of course if you need lower->upper and upper->lower at the same time you can apply `~` on the visually selected text.

Comment: `upperCase($Column Header$)` in _KNIME_. You could also use [several nodes](https://forum.knime.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-convert-all-column-names-to-uppercase/8155/2): Extract Column Header, Transpose, String Manipulation, and Insert Column Header nodes.

Comment: Note that `\L` works the same way but for lower case. `\L$1\E` to lower in Sublime Text

Comment: In VS Code find and replace method, \U$1 works.

Comment: This applies to IDEs like IntelliJ too!

Comment: Perfect! Works in VSCode with `\U$1`

Comment: I knew this was a thing, but I'm so confused why it only works in REPLACE, not FIND. So essentially FIND: \U\w\E\w+ is impossible without re-creating the \w class from scratch, which is basically impossible?

Answer (score 44):

I know this thread is about EditPad Pro, but I came here because I had the same need with a javascript regexp.

For the people who are here needing the same tip, you can use a function or lambda as the replace argument.

I use the function below to convert css names with `-` to the javascript equivalent, for example, `"border-top"` will be transformed into `"borderTop"`:

```js
    s = s.replace(/\-[a-z]/g, x => x[1].toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 34):

> EditPad Pro and PowerGREP have a
>   unique feature that allows you to
>   change the case of the backreference.
>   `\U1` inserts the first backreference
>   in uppercase, `\L1` in lowercase and
>   `\F1` with the first character in
>   uppercase and the remainder in
>   lowercase. Finally, `\I1` inserts it
>   with the first letter of each word
>   capitalized, and the other letters in
>   lowercase.

Source: Goyvaerts, Jan (2006). *Regular Expressions: The Complete Tutorial*. Lulu.com. [p. 35](https://books.google.com/books?id=2IOZA74lnbsC&lpg=PA35&pg=PA35&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false). ISBN 1411677609. Google Books. Retrieved on June 25, 2010.

Answer (score 12):

Just an **another ussage example for Notepad++** (regular expression search mode)

```
Find: (g|c|u|d)(et|reate|pdate|elete)_(.)([^\s (]+)
Replace: \U\1\E$2\U\3\E$4
```

**Example:**

```
get_user -> GetUser
create_user -> CreateUser
update_user -> UpdateUser
delete_user -> DeleteUser
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also capitalize the first letter of the match using `\I1` and `\I2` etc instead of `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in jEdit, by using the "Return value of a BeanShell snippet" option in jEdit's find and replace dialog. Just search for `" [a-z]"` and replace it by `" _0.toUpperCase()"` (without quotes)

Comment: Your response is not really related to the initial question, but I found it while googling and was exactly what I was looking for. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For **javascript users** (i fell here coming from javascript) **check this answer** https://stackoverflow.com/a/73776269/7668448

Examples and reference

### API

```
replace(
    regex,
    (matched, capture1, capture2, /*...,*/ capture_n, index, input_str) => transformed(/*...*/)
)
```

```
replace(
    regex: Regex,
    transformer: (matched: string, capture1: string, capture2: string, /*...,*/ capture_n: string, index: number, input_str: string) => string
) => string
```

Check the answer for the examples. Converting swc command args to camel case js equiv.