# How to replace full file name with random number?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my code

```
"test.html".replace(/(?=\.[^.]+$)/g, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1))
```

How to convert test.html to random number.html like 38475.html?

Comment: do you have to use regex?

Comment: `"test.html".replace(/^.+(?=\.[^.]+)/, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1))`

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only?rq=1

Comment: http://regex101.com is your friend

Answer (score 2):

if regex is not mandatory :), then try

```
 Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1) + "." + "test.html".split( "." ).pop();
```

create a method

```
function randomizeFileName( fileName )
{
   return Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1) + "." + fileName.split( "." ).pop();
}
```

Comment: any reason for using split.pop() instead lastIndexOf()?

Comment: @PavanTeja No specific reason, I just prefer to array methods as they are more readable and cleaner to use.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to use regex here?
you can just use the randaom number appended with file extension of actual file.

```
 var fileName="test.html";

 fileName= Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1)+fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))
```