# JS .replace with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a text like this

Right (99.99руб.) OR 
Left with space (руб. 99.99) OR 
Right with space (99.99 руб.) OR 
Left (руб.99.99)

I want to find and change currency symbol with my new symbol.

Here is my code for example

```
var str = "Right (99.99руб.)",
    symbol = '&&';

console.log(str.replace(/\(\d+\.?\d+\s?(.+)\)|\(([^0-9^\s]+)\s?\d+\.\d+\)/g, symbol))
```

But it replaces all the text that i have find with regex ("(99.99руб.)") instead of text in captured group ("руб.").

How can i replace only matched text ?

P.S Thanks in advance
P.S.S Sorry for my english

Comment: You did not use the backreference. What is the expected output? Try `symbol = "&&\1"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Regex, how to replace the captured groups only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only)

Comment: @WiktorStribizew  expected output is "Right (99.99&&)"

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
руб\.\ ?(\d[\d.]+)|(\d[\d.]*)\ ?руб
```

And replace it with `$1$2&&`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cQ5uO6/2).

---

In `JavaScript`:

```
var string = 'Right (99.99руб.) OR Left with space (руб. 99.99) OR Right with space (99.99 руб.) OR Left (руб.99.99)';
var re = /руб\.\ ?(\d[\d.]+)|(\d[\d.]*)\ ?руб/g;
string = string.replace(re, '$1$2&&');
alert(string);
```

See a JS fiddle on [**jsfiddle.net**](https://jsfiddle.net/cv26kLhe/).

Comment: it must work with any currency not only руб.

string can be Left with space (৳ 99.99)

Comment: and you don't need to work with 
"Right (99.99руб.) OR Left with space (руб. 99.99) OR Right with space (99.99 руб.) OR Left (руб.99.99)"

It would be better to write 

I have a text like one of these

"Right (99.99руб.)" or "Left with space (руб. 99.99)" or "Right with space (99.99 руб.)" or "Left (руб.99.99)"

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/kR2sX3/1, you can add the symbols on the go to the alternation groups.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew it always puts currency symbol at the end of the string

Comment: :) Isn't that what you need? Please update your question with what you need.