# Using RegEx to create div with classname

Tags: javascript, regex

Using RegEx, I want to replace construction in my example into a div.

So, before:

```
::: foo
some text
:::
```

After:

```
<div class="foo">
some text
</div>
```

I found how it may be done ([test](http://regexr.com/3famr)), but my solution works for only one class. In other words, class is hard-coded into script:

```
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(/(:::\s?[a-z])\w+/, 'g'), '<div class="foo">');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(/:::/, 'g'), '</div>');
</script>
```

How it may be changed, so it will work for any class name? For example, these constructions should be also converted into divs:

```
::: foobarfoo
some text
:::
```

and

```
::: foo-bar-foo_bar_foo123-foo
some text
:::
```

Comment: You need to [use captured groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references), that is, put part of your regex in parentheses and then that part of the match will be captured for use in the replacement, where you can reference it with `$1`:

```
var text = document.body.innerHTML;
text = text.replace(/:::\s?([^\s:]+)/g, '<div class="$1">')
text = text.replace(/:::/g, '</div>');
document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

If you had more than one capturing group in the same regex the second and subsequent ones would be referenced by `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Note that you should avoid repeatedly updating `document.body.innerHTML` - better to put the original text into a variable, then do your replacements with that variable, then finally write the end result back to `document.body.innerHTML`. You can also chain the `.replace()` calls:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
                           .replace(/:::\s?([^\s:]+)/g, '<div class="$1">')
                           .replace(/:::/g, '</div>');
```

Note also that you don't need to call `new RegExp()`, because the `/` at the beginning and end of the regex is the regex literal syntax that creates a regular expression object on its own.

Comment: It works, and also, compared with some another answers, it really clean and easy to understand.

Comment: I forgot to explain in my answer, but (aside from the parentheses) where you had `[a-z]\w+` I changed it to `[^\s:]+`, that is, to match any characters other than spaces and colons. That made more sense to *me*, but obviously you can use `[a-z]\w+` or whatever else meets your needs. The parentheses/capturing groups is the main point of the question and answer.