# How to replace RegExp capture groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

In a string, I need to replace all occurences of `[A]`, `"A"`, `'A'` and `_A_` with `[X]`, `"X"`, `'X'` and `_X_`. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only) but it's giving a weird result (code below). I use `new RegExp` because it allows interpolating a variable -- `A` and `X` are just an example.

```
// CAPTURE GROUPS:       |------1-----|2|-----3------|
var regexp = new RegExp('(\'|\"|\_|\[)(A)(\'|\"|\_|\])', 'g')
var string = ' [A] _A_ "A" \'A\' A BAB "B" '
string.replace(regex, '$1X$3')

// ORIGINAL: [A] _A_ "A" 'A' A BAB "B" 
// EXPECTED: [X] _X_ "X" 'X' A BAB "B"
// ACTUAL:   [X] XXX XXX XXX X BXB XBX
```

Comment: When you build a regular expression from a string like that, the backslash escape characters must be **doubled**.

Comment: To prevent what pointy pointed (\*g\*) out, use the Regex literal syntax instead of the constructor.

Comment: @Pointy doubling the backslash **only before the square brackets** works! -- but doubling the others gives syntax error, just for the record.

Comment: @Christoph I don't think it's possible to interpolate a variable in a regex literal. As I said, 2 and X are just examples. The actual value is in a variable so I need the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the two layers of interpretation that the backslashes undergo. First you have JavaScript's string literal syntax, which uses backslashes to escape characters. When you have a string like

```
'(\'|\"|\_|\[)(A)(\'|\"|\_|\])'
```

in your code, the actual contents are:

```
('|"|_|[)(A)('|"|_|])
```

This is then parsed by the RegExp constructor, which treats `[)(A)('|"|_|]` as a single character class equivalent to `[A'"_()|]`.

To preserve a backslash so the regexp engine can see it, you have to put two backslashes in your string.

You can also use character classes to simplify your code a bit:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('([\'"_[])A([\'"_\\]])', 'g')
var string = ' [A] _A_ "A" \'A\' A BAB "B" '
console.log(string.replace(regex, '$1X$2'));
```