# Javascript - how to use regex process the following complicated string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following string that will occur repeatedly in a larger string:

`[SM_g]word[SM_h].[SM_l] &quot;`

Notice in this string after the phrase "[SM_g]word[Sm_h]" there are three components:

1. A period (.) This could also be a comma (,)
2. [SM_l]
3. `&quot;`

Zero to all three of these components will always appear after "[SM_g]word[SM_h]". However, they can also appear in any order after "[SM_g]word[SM_h]". For example, the string could also be:

`[SM_g]word[SM_h][SM_l]&quot;`

or

`[SM_g]word[SM_h]&quot;[SM_l].`

or

`[SM_g]word[SM_h]&quot;.`

or

`[SM_g]word[SM_h][SM_1].`

or

`[SM_g]word[SM_h].`

or simply just

`[SM_g]word[SM_h]`

These are just some of the examples. The point is that there are three different components (more if you consider the period can also be a comma) that can appear after "[SM_h]word[SM_g]" where these three components can be in any order *and* sometimes one, two, or all three of the components will be missing.

Not only that, sometimes there will be up to one space before " and the previous component/[SM_g]word[SM_h].

For example:

`[SM_g]word[SM_h] &quot;.`

or

`[SM_g]word[SM_h][SM_l] &quot;.`

etc. etc.

I am trying to process this string by moving each of the three components inside of the core string (and preserving the space, in case there is a space before &\quot; and the previous component/[SM_g]word[SM_h]).

For example, `[SM_g]word[SM_h].[SM_l]&quot;` would turn into

`[SM_g]word.[SM_l]&quot;[SM_h]`

or

`[SM_g]word[SM_h]&quot;[SM_l].` would turn into

`[SM_g]word&quot;[SM_l].[SM_h]`

or, to simulate having a space before `&quot;`

`[SM_g]word[SM_h] &quot;.`

would turn into

`[SM_g]word &quot;.[SM_h]`

and so on.

I've tried several combinations of regex expressions, and none of them have worked.

Does anyone have advice?

Comment: You can change the `&` to `&amp;` to get the format you want.

Comment: You can use code blocks for literal code: `&quot;` Use `>` for quoting (ordinary text), not for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put each component within an alternation in a grouping construct with maximum match try of `3` if it is necessary:

```
\[SM_g]word(\[SM_h])((?:\.|\[SM_l]| ?&quot;){0,3})
```

You may replace `word` with `.*?` if it is not a constant or specific keyword.

Then in replacement string you should do:

```
$1$3$2
```

```js
var re = /(\[SM_g]word)(\[SM_h])((?:\.|\[SM_l]| ?&quot;){0,3})/g;
var str = `[SM_g]word[SM_h][SM_l] &quot;.`;

console.log(str.replace(re, `$1$3$2`));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems applicable for your process, in other word, `changing sub-string position`.

```
(\[SM_g])([^[]*)(\[SM_h])((?=([,\.])|(\[SM_l])|( ?&\\?quot;)).*)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/119),,, in which all sub-strings are captured to each `capture group` respectively for your `post processing`.

`[SM_g]` is captured to group`1`, `word` to group`2`, `[SM_h]` to group`3`, and string of `all trailing part` is to group`4`, `[,\.]` to group`5`, `[SM_l]` to group`6`, " `?&\\?quot;`" to group`7`.

Thus, group`1~3` are `core part`, group`4` is `trailing part` for checking if trailing part exists, and group`5~7` are `sub-parts of group4` for your post processing.

Therefore, you can get easily matched string's `position changed output string` in the order of what you want by `replacing with captured groups` like follows.

```
\1\2\7\3 or $1$2$7$3  etc..
```

For replacing in Javascript, please refer to this post. [JS Regex, how to replace the captured groups only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only)

But above regex is not sufficiently precise because it may allow any `repeatitions of the sub-part` of the trailing string, for example, `\1\2\3\5\5\5\5` or `\1\2\3\6\7\7\7\7\5\5\5`, etc..

To avoid this situation, it needs to adopt condition which accepts only the possible `combinations` of the sub-parts of the trailing string. Please refer to this example. https://regex101.com/r/6aM4Pv/1/ for the possible `combinations` in the order.

But if the regex adopts the condition of `allowing only possible combinations`, the regex will be more complicated so I leave the above simplified regex to help you understand about it. Thank you:-)