# Javascript - Create Regex Character Class

Tags: javascript, regex, character-class

Is there a way to use javascript's regex engine to create a character class that matches with

`&quot;` or `&quot;` (one space before `&quot;`) or `.` or `,` or `[SM_l]`
or nothing (not the string "nothing" , just 0 characters)

Background Context: This is going to be used as part of the solution to solve the problem presented in this post: [Javascript - how to use regex process the following complicated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912307/javascript-how-to-use-regex-process-the-following-complicated-string)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have no clue on how to do this. This is part of a way to solve a different, larger, problem that I have already tried solving. I edited my post with context.

Comment: Isn't it the same issue as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912307/javascript-how-to-use-regex-process-the-following-complicated-string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't think it was the same thing - the previous post can have multiple different solutions. For example - I solved the previous problem with regex in a completely different manner, than the way I am describing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't a character class. A character class `[...]` denotes a match on every individual unit of data in it by which`[&quot;]+` means characters `&`, `q`, `u`, `o`, `t` or `;` in any order, with or without all characters:

- `&quot;`
- `&uot;`
- `;&`

What you need is called grouping. You just need a `|` inside a grouping construct to imply `OR` conditions (that I also applied in an answer to [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912307/javascript-how-to-use-regex-process-the-following-complicated-string))

> `&quot;` or `&quot;` (one space before `&quot;`)

means `[ ]?&quot;`

> `.` or `,` or `[SM_l]`

means `(\.|,|\[SM_l])` that could be reduced to `([.,]|\[SM_l])`

Putting all together you need:

```
([ ]?&quot;|[.,]|\[SM_l])?
```

Question mark denotes an optional match.

Comment: I noticed in your previous answer that you said ` ?&quot;` instead of `[ ]?quot;` is there any real difference between the two, or is one better than the other?

Comment: No there is no real difference. Literal spaces are vague inside code blocks. Hence, I used a character class to overcome this issue.