# Extracting the property of an HTML element using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, web-scraping

I'm working on some image deferring and am looking for a way to remove the src element. I have a specific use case where I need to use regex so I can render the result server-side and stop the src from loading, until I tell it to in JS.

Basically I need a way to reliably replace just the `src` in an image tag. Not the value, but the actual property name.

As of right now, I was testing something along the lines of:

`<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"][^>]*>`.

Which given my example text, finds the whole string `<img src="aaaa" />`. I basically need it to only highlight the `src`. That way I can regex_replace on it to change `src` to `data-deferred`.

Example Text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis bibendum lorem bibendum lectus rhoncus molestie. <img src ="aaaa" /> Maecenas ipsum justo, fermentum nec lacus in, porta consectetur metus.
```

Here is my Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/RATGgw/1/

Since I don't always have access to the HTML I'm going to have to parse, I can't just target `src`. I need to make sure it's only `src` when found anywhere within an image tag.

Any idea how I could modify this to accomplish this?

Edit:

For clarification, the question, how can I use RegEx to be able to find only the `src` property within an image tag.

So my found result would allow me to replace `src="https://"` with a custom data-attribute like `data-deferred="https://"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `src` property with a `data-deferred` property by using capturing groups (parentheses) in your regex like this:

```js
//           [    $1   ][$2 ][?= a lookahead (no capture)  ][global - replace all]
var regex = /(<img[^>]+)(src)(?=\s*=\s*['"][^'"]+['"][^>]*>)/g;
var text = 'Lorem ipsum. <img alt="foo" src ="aaaa" title="bar" /> Maecenas metus.';

var result = text.replace(regex, '$1data-deferred'); 

console.log(result);
// Lorem ipsum. <img alt="foo" data-deferred ="aaaa" title="bar" /> Maecenas metus.
```

Comment: I know my wording may have been confusing, but I am unable to match just the text "src". As in, I want to basically turn `src="aaaa"` into `data-deferred="aaaa"`. Basically replacing my src property for a custom data attribute.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I did not understand at first. Updated my answer, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yup basically what I'm looking for. Just out of curiosity, is that regex cascading, as in it finds the full, then splits to groups? Is there a way to only find the src group?

Comment: Well, I found _some_ improvements: no capturing group for the end part, using a lookahead, and no more use of a callback function for the replacement. There might be a way to remove the first capturing group, but I couldn't find one that worked. [This might be the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450029/1913729) but it just freezes my Chrome

Comment: Oh, and I added a `g` flag (global) in case you want to replace multiple occurrences

Comment: Hmm, this is such a weird problem lol. No worries though, that looks like the right track! Appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use jQuery for things like this:

```
$('img[data-deferred]').each(function(i, img){
  $(img).attr('src', $(img).attr('data-deferred'))
})
```

Comment: Given my constraints, I'm trying to accomplish this server side and only have access to Jinja2, but their regex-replacement options are kind of lacking. I want the src stripped far when it renders, not after the dom is ready.