# Regex Package.json Replace App Version With Variable and String

Tags: json, regex, npm, package.json

I am trying to replace the version number in a couple of files using the package.json file and "replace": "1.1.0" by running an npm script.  I am running into a Regex issue I believe with the replace.  I think maybe the solution should be some kind of regex grouping where I just replace the `.*` value with just `$npm_package_version` = solved, but I don't know how to do that.

Package.json version = `"version": "2.0.45",`

Strings to find = `"ApiVersion": "Any number and periods like this 1.2.67",`

Code Attempted =  `"updateVersion": "replace \"\"ApiVersion\": .*\",\" \"\"ApiVersion\": \"$npm_package_version\",\" ../appsettings.json",`

Expected Outcome = in file appsetting.json the ApiVersion should be changed to = `"ApiVersion": "2.0.45",`

Error Received = `"ApiVersion": "$npm_package_version",`

I am assuming there is something going on here with regex, but I can't figure out how to get the npm package version var to render inside the string value.  It works just as `$npm_package_version`.

Answer (score 0):

finally got it.  This is supppper useful in my book.

```
postversion": "replace '(?<=\"ApiVersion\":\\s\").*(?=\",)' $npm_package_version ../appsettings.json",
```

To explain the parathesis (text in here) creates a group.  The `?<=` creates a Lookbehind.  The `\\s` match any whitespace - double escaped. The `.*` matches all in between the two-match requirements. The `?=` creates a look ahead.  So Look/Match step through = "ApiVersion": any space " anything between ", replace only the in-between with the npm variable.

I think that is close to what it really does - not a regex expert.

Got help here -[How to replace captured groups only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/how-to-replace-captured-groups-only)