# RegExp find wrong tags

Tags: regex

I have some urls saved in DB like `<a href="some/site/hello.html<br/>">hello world</a>`
with break tags, so i need to delete them, the problem that `<br/>` are in other places to so i can't delete all of them,
i write RegExp `<*"*<br\/?>">` but it select not only `<br>` and quotes too.

Comment: [A regex is not the good tool to parse HTML nor XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2123530)

Comment: Create capturing group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/how-to-replace-captured-groups-only  (it's for Java but idea is the same)

Comment: You mean you need to delete the urls with break tags in them completely, or just take out the `<br/>` if it is inside an url? P.S. What language?  C#, PHP, PowerShell, something else??

Comment: its in PHP, the answers that are bellow helps me to resolve my problem, thanks you guys too.

Comment: `\`<a href="hbla.<br>\"bla" bc="</a>" d='sbc'>testt</a>\`.match(/<a\s(?:[\w\W]+?(["'])[\w\W]+?(?:\\\1[\w\W]*?)*\1)*[\w\W]*?>[\w\W]*?<\/a>/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using regular expressions for parsing HTML or XML.

Having said that. As I understand it, you have br tags inside the href attribute of a tags.

try :

```regex
href\s*?=\s*?\"(.*?)(<br\/?\>)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to search about the right lines in the database, then this is your regex extended to match the whole line:

```
<.*\".*<br\/>\">.*>
```

After this you can mach the '<br/>' directly in those lines. Is there a language to edit your DB?

Comment: yes i work with PHP, and some users save hrefs like `<a href="some/site.html
"> my_site</a>`
than that rows parse from DB and format with regExp changin all `\n` to `<br/>`, so if user press enter inside href tag and save it, it will be with `<br/>`,

Answer (score 0):

**Some of the other answers here are okay. I'll offer an alternative:**
https://regex101.com/r/uG5PBA/2

**This'll put the break tags in a capture group -- group 1, so that you can simply nix them.**

**Regex:**

```
<a[\s\S]*?(\<br\/>)[\s\S]*?<\/a>
```

**Test String:**

```
<a href="some/site/hello.html<br/>">hello world</a><a href="some/site/hello.html<br/>">hello world</a>
```

Comment: Glad to hear! :D

Comment: You could also do a substitution like this: https://regex101.com/r/uG5PBA/3 -- just throwing it out there.