# How to only catch what's between quotation marks in the following regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex matches substrings inside quotation marks:

```
^("[^"]*")$
```

> "Dialogue," she said. "More dialogue."

I don't want to catch the quotation marks (only what's inside the quotation marks). So I figured I should use a lookahead and a lookbehind:

```
^((?<=")[^"]*(?="))$
```

But now the regex isn't matching anything.

Why is this? And how to fix it?

https://regexr.com/5spdt

EDIT: Removing the outer capture group kind of worked, but now `she said` is being caputerd too. `(?<=")[^"]*(?=")`

Comment: You can remove the anchors and the capture group `(?<=")[^"]*(?=")`

Comment: @Thefourthbird That kind of worked ... but now the `she said` is being captured too.

Comment: For the example string, I only see a match for `Dialogue,` see https://regex101.com/r/J0lPpH/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That happens when there's another quote behind: https://regex101.com/r/CVSJxM/1

Comment: Then you might use `(?<=")[^"]*(?="(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/dzO0ti/1

Comment: @AD7six I don't want to capture the "'s. I only want to capture what's inside the "'s.

Comment: Would a non-matching around your quotation marks group be sufficient to your needs? https://regexr.com/5spfj

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace captured groups only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/how-to-replace-captured-groups-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get too much matches, as the assertions to not match the `"` so anything between 2 double quotes is a match.

You can assert a `"` to the left, the match all except `"` until you can assert a `"` to the right followed by optional pairs of `""` till the end of the string.

Assuming no escaped double quotes between the double quotes

```
 (?<=")[^"]*(?="(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

- `(?<=")` Positive lookbehind, assert `"` directly to the left of the current position
- `[^"]*` Match 0+ times any char except `"`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `"` Match closing `"`
  - `(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*` Match optional pairs of `""`
  - `[^"]*$` Match option char other than `"` and assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dzO0ti/1)

Comment: @alexchenco I think it will be even longer if you want to allow escaped `\"` between the double quotes.

Comment: It will be something like this https://regex101.com/r/rXeJfz/1

Answer (score 1):

## KISS

The regex in the question is overly specific (exploded):

```
^        # Start of string
(        # Begin capturing group
"
[^"]*
"
)        # End capturing group
$        # End of string
```

This will only match strings of the form:

```
"some string"
```

It would not, for example, match strings of the form:

```
anything "some string"   (does not start with a quote
"some string" anything   (does not end with a quote)
```

So given the goal is to capture quoted strings, just don't include the quotes in the capturing group:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

And then reference the capturing group, not the whole matching string.

## Applied to Javascript

Consider the following code:

```
input = '"one" something "two" something "three" etc.';
regex = /"([^"]*)"/;
match = input.match(regex);
```

Match contains: `["\"one\"", "one"]` - the 0 entry is the full matching string, the 1 entry is the *first capturing group*. Adapt js code as relevant.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm doing `.replace`, so I guess I can write `"..."` in the replace argument if I want to keep the quotes.

Comment: er ok, so it's an x/y problem. Please always ask what you want to do, not how you are currently trying to solve it (:.