# regex replace only outer brackets of nested parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking to preserve inner nested brackets when replacing brackets. If possible to make many nested layers work that would be great, if not just nested once is fine.

```
(if money>5 and (times + total_cash >266))[something]
(if times + total_cash >266)[something]

{if money>5 and (times + total_cash >266)}[something]
{if times + total_cash >266}[something]
```

A naive attempt doesn't seem to work that well:

```
str.replace(/\(if(.*?)\)]/gi, '{if $1}')
```

Comment: Not possible to deal with several levels of nested brackets with javascript regex. You have to write a state machine.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte okay, but 1 is still possible right? Do you know what the limit is?

Comment: If you know that 1 is the max, yes it's possible.

Comment: The limit is the limit you know in advance, but the pattern grows with the nesting levels (at least with javascript because you can't build recursive patterns).

Comment: If the outer left parenthesis is the first left parenthesis in the string and the outer right parenthesis is the last right parenthesis in the string you can match the regex `^[^\(]*(\().*(\))[^\)]*$` and convert the content of capture group 1 (a left parenthesis) to `'{'` and and convert the content of capture group 2 (a right parenthesis) to `'}'`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uuGALV/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland how do you replace only the captured group? I thought you had to capture everything else to do replace it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/how-to-replace-captured-groups-only

Comment: Each match will have two captures; capture group 1 holds `'('` , capture group 2 holds `')'` . You should be able to programmatically get the index in the string for each of those captures and make the substitution. I don't know Javascript but to give you an idea of how to do it, here is how you would do that in Ruby (which resembles pseudo-code):  `s= "cat (if times + total_cash >266)[something] dog"; m = /^[^\(]*(\().*(\))[^\)]*$/.match(s); i = m.begin(1) #=> 4; j = m.begin(2) #=> 31; s[4] = '{'; s[31] = '}'; s #=> "cat {if times + total_cash >266}[something] dog"`.

Comment: Similar @CarySwoveland's suggestion, if input matches this pattern, even [`\((.*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/a9CtGd/1) might suffice (replace with capture `{$1}`).

Comment: @bobble bubble isn't that the same as what I had in the question, that doesn't capture the last closing parenthesis it captures the one before it.

Comment: @Harry Oh, yours was very similar indeed - with a minor difference - your `.*?` is [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) whereas my `.*` is greedy (hungry/consumes as much as possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for zero level of nesting:

```
str.replace(/\(if\s*([^()]*)\)/gi, '{if $1}')
```

for one level (or less):

```
str.replace(/\(if\s*([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*)\)/gi, '{if $1}')
```

for two levels (or less):

```
str.replace(/\(if\s*([^()]*(?:\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)[^()]*)*)\)/gi, '{if $1}')
```

etc. This method becomes quickly limited.

Javascript regexes don't have features like recursive patterns (perl, pcre), or a counter system like in .net languages.
That's why, the best option is to build a state machine to count the number of opening and closing parenthesis (note that you can use a regex to split your string to interesting parts to do it, for example: `str.split(/(\bif\b|[()])/i)`).

---

Note that `[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*` is an optimized way to write: `(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*` (that is shorter but inefficient). This subpattern is *unrolled*.

Comment: Thanks learned something, might have some followup questions.

Comment: @Harry: note that things become more complicated if you have to deal with strings or comments inside which brackets are ignored.