# Convert Unicode symbols to HTML with Qt

Tags: html, qt, unicode

I have a string, which looks, for example, like this:

```
SYMBOLSU+2510\n
```

This string has Unicode character `U+2510` and new line symbol `\n`. I have a log window, which draws HTML. Dows it possible to convert in some way this string to HLMT, because when I just text this string to the log window it's written as it is `SYMBOLSU+2510\n`, but I need convert `U+2510` to its HTML representation and to draw HTML symbol.

Thanks for the help!

PS. Sorry if I messed some definitions, this encoding thing is not something I good at.
PPS I use Qt5.

Comment: Start by writing code which _finds_ and prints all "U-xxxx" substrings. If you can't, ask about that code. Next step, replace these with `.`. next step, replace these with correct unicode character. Next step, handle `\\` escape codes. You now have a correct unicode string. Next step, convert it to HTML text (there should be a function for that, don't need to implement it yourself).

Comment: That's a good point, but here you are talking about manually replacing all these characters. I thought, that maybe there are some special functions exist

Comment: No, I'm talking about writing the special function. But, for HTML, you can actually directly replace the markup around the code, without never interpreting it, as shown by the (currently only) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify any particular language; for instance, in Python ([replace merely captured group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/)):

```
import re
symbols = 'U+250cSYMBOLSU+2510\n'
re.sub("U\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})", "&#x\\1;", symbols)
```

returns `&#x250c;SYMBOLS&#x2510;\n` which renders as

*┌SYMBOLS┐\n*

in a browser.