# How to change case of letters in string using RegEx in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have a string :   "hEY "

I want to convert it to "Hey "

```
string.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z]+ )/, '\1'.upcase)
```

That is the idea I have, but it seems like the upcase method does nothing when I use it within the gsub method.  Why is that?

EDIT: I came up with this method:

```
string.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z]+ )/) { |str| str.downcase!.capitalize! }
```

Is there a way to do this within the regex though?  I don't really understand the '\1' '\2' thing.  Is that backreferencing?  How does that work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@sawa Has the simple answer, and you've edited your question with another mechanism. However, to answer two of your questions:

> *Is there a way to do this within the regex though?*

No, Ruby's regex does not support a case-changing feature as [some other regex flavors do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159343/convert-a-char-to-upper-case-using-regular-expressions-editpad-pro). You can "prove" this to yourself by reviewing the official Ruby regex docs for 1.9 and 2.0 and searching for the word "case":

- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/doc/re.rdoc
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/doc/re.rdoc

> *I don't really understand the '\1' '\2' thing. Is that backreferencing? How does that work?*

Your use of `\1` is a kind of backreference. A backreference can be when you use `\1` and such in the search pattern. For example, the regular expression `/f(.)\1/` will find the letter `f`, followed by any character, followed by that same character (e.g. "foo" or "f!!").

In this case, within a replacement string passed to a method like `String#gsub`, the backreference does refer to the previous capture. From the docs:

> "If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form `\d`, where `d` is a group number, or `\k<n>`, where `n` is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash."

In practice, this means:

```
"hello world".gsub( /([aeiou])/, '_\1_' )  #=> "h_e_ll_o_ w_o_rld"
"hello world".gsub( /([aeiou])/, "_\1_" )  #=> "h_\u0001_ll_\u0001_ w_\u0001_rld"
"hello world".gsub( /([aeiou])/, "_\\1_" ) #=> "h_e_ll_o_ w_o_rld"
```

Now, you have to understand when code runs. In your original code…

```
string.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z]+ )/, '\1'.upcase)
```

…what you are doing is calling `upcase` on the string `'\1'` (which has no effect) and *then* calling the `gsub!` method, passing in a regex and a string as parameters.

Finally, another way to achieve this same goal is with the block form like so:

```
# Take your pick of which you prefer:
string.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z]+ )/){ $1.upcase << $2.downcase }
string.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z]+ )/){ [$1.upcase,$2.downcase].join }
string.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z]+ )/){ "#{$1.upcase}#{$2.downcase}" }
```

In the block form of gsub the captured patterns are set to the global variables `$1`, `$2`, etc. and you can use those to construct the replacement string.

Comment: so the dollar signs are how you backreference in the block form?

Comment: @ordinary Sort of. After any regex match is made Ruby updates the global variables `$1` et al. They just happen to be available in the block form in addition to other locations.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why you are trying to do it in a complicated way, but the usual way is:

```
"hEY".capitalize # => "Hey"
```

If you insist in using a regex and `upcase`, then you would also need `downcase`:

```
"hEY".downcase.sub(/\w/){$&.upcase} # => "Hey"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to just swap the case of every letter in the string, you can avoid the complexity of regex entirely because There's A Method For That™.

```
"hEY".swapcase # => "Hey"
"HellO thERe".swapcase # => "hELLo THerE"
```

There's also `swapcase!` to do it destructively.