# regex to change href link to lowercase

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, case-sensitive, lowercase

I have pages with links like:

```
href="FileName-One-Example.html"
```

I need to a regular expression command with Notepad++ to change the case of the anything between `href="` nad the ending `"` to lowercase, and leave everything before and after it in the page as is.

So the result is:

```
href="filename-one-example.html"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the correct regexp to use:

```
Find: (href=")([^"]*)
Replace: \1\L\2\E
```

Edit: changed the second `\L` to `\E` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Note that the text to be lower-cased must be between the two `\L`.

Comment: @Omar That is incorrect. You need to put "\E" when you want to stop the "upper/lower" command. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159343/convert-a-char-to-upper-case-using-regular-expressions-editpad-pro

Comment: I used Notepad++ to convert naming conventions in a load of C# code (hundreds of files).  The old convention for fields was `mAbcXyz` and the new was `_abcXyz` (meaning I wanted to change the case of the first character after the initial "m" to be lower).  The result was:
Find:  `\b(m)([A-Z])([A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b`
Replace:  `_\L$2\E$3`
Note the `\E` after the first character has been converted to lower case in the replacement expression.