# How to transform the first character of a word to uppercase with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, replace

I'm looking for a way to change the first character of every word in a sentence form lowercase to uppercase. I already read the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159343/convert-a-char-to-upper-case-using-regular-expressions-editpad-pro/1159389#1159389) but it doesn't work.

I tried to use `\U` to replace the first letter as an uppercase letter. But it returns \U as the replacement, not the first letter. May someone take a look at http://regexr.com?36h59

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It depends on the regex variant, not all variants can do this. So where/how will you execute this for real?

Comment: please specify a language.

Comment: Nothing you can do if the regex implementation you're using doesn't support the functionality to do this (`\U`).

Comment: Nobody knows what you think is a 'word'. Until, or unless, you define that, there is nothing that can help you. No utilities, no guesses, nothing, letters can start after any non-letters. The non-letter class is humonguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text transformations are possible depends on the regexp implementation. Most standard implementations base off Perl regular expressions and do not support this.

A lot of text editors however do provide some way of transformations as they do not have any other capabilities of processing a regular expression match. For example the answer in your linked question refers to an editor called “TextPad”. These transformations are often non-standard and can also differ a lot depending on what tool you use. When using programming languages however, you don’t really need those features built into the regular expression syntax, as you can easily store the match and do some further processing on your own. A lot language also allow you to supply a function which is then called to process every replacement individually.

If you tell us what language you are using, we might be able to help you further.

#### Some examples

JavaScript:

```
> text = 'anleitungen gesundes wohnen';
> text.replace(/(\w+)/g, function(x) { return x[0].toUpperCase() + x.substring(1) });
'Anleitungen Gesundes Wohnen'
```

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'anleitungen gesundes wohnen'
>>> re.sub('(\w+)', lambda x: x.group(0).capitalize(), text)
'Anleitungen Gesundes Wohnen'
```

Comment: I use the addon "SEO Tools for Excel" by Niels Bosma. The built-in "RegexpReplace" Function is based on. Net regular expressions. http://nielsbosma.se/projects/seotools/functions/regexpreplace/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is more a kind of end-user problem ;-)

Comment: While the .NET regular expressions do support a similar replacement function as shown in the examples above, I’m afraid you won’t be able to use them in that Excel function. However, there is a built-in Excel function that does exactly what you need: It capitalizes every word. The function is called `PROPER` (`GROSS2` in German). So you could just use `=PROPER("anleitungen gesundes wohnen")` or even `=PROPER(RegexpIsFind(...))` to transform the text.

Answer (score 0):

### javascript

```
 str.replace(/' '([a-z])+/, foo);

function foo(x){
    return x.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Syntax error; would transform all characters, not just the first of a word; and also the desired casing is upper case, not lower case.

Comment: @poke sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'xyzzy plugh dwarf' | sed 's/\(\<.\)\.*/\u\1/g' 
Xyzzy Plugh Dwarf
```

Comment: I think You forgot to erase the "\.*" portion - feel free to update the answer, so I could upvote :)

Comment: Ok well the osx/bsd version of sed doesn't have \u so it doesn't work there.

Answer (score -1):

If your coding using PHP check out the manual here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: Given that there are probably hundreds of regex implementations, PHP is ... improbable, to say the least.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking more for a general answer.