# Notepad++ Regex Force Upper/Lower Case Broken?

Tags: regex, notepad++, uppercase, lowercase

Searching: (WORD)
Replacing: \L\1
Got: \LWORD

Searching: (WORD)
Replacing: \L\1\E
Got: \LWORD\E

Searching: (WORD)
Replacing: \L$1
Got: \L$1

I'm lost.

The question is, what am I doing wrong?  The radio button is selected, and the commands just don't produce the results I expect.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was pretty clear that I was trying and failing to get good results from the search/replace regex terms.  I've been reading for an hour to find other options for this result, but none of them worked at all.  I think my notepad++ is broken because I think, from reading other articles here, these search replace strings should be resulting in "word", but they don't.

Answer (score 1):

- use `\U\1` for upper case
- use `\L\1` for lower case

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159343/convert-a-char-to-upper-case-using-regular-expressions-editpad-pro)

Never forget to check the regular expression radio button.

[image]

`\L$1` is also working fine

[image]