# Convert first lowercase to uppercase and uppercase to lowercase (regex?)

Tags: notepad++, case-sensitive, uppercase, lowercase, emeditor

I have a huge file in this layout:

```
world12345:Betaalpha    
world12344:alphabeta    
world12343:ZetaBeta    
world12342:!betatheta
```

I need to convert the first lowercase letter after the ":" to uppercase and the first uppercase letter to lowercase. 
I've tried using notepad++ and emeditor, but I'm not that experienced with regex.

This is how I want it to become after (regex?)

```
world12345:betaalpha    
world12344:Alphabeta    
world12343:zetaBeta    
world12342:!betatheta   (unchanged, as the first char is a special char)
```

I have tried searching the web for a regex in npp+, but to no avail.
Unfortunately, I'm not a scripter so I can't write one myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1159389/9882907), I was able to find a solution to your problem after initially thinking it wasn't possible.

The way to do this in Notepad++ is to use the following options:

- Open the Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Find what: `^([^:]+:)(([A-Z])|([a-z]))([^:]+)$`
- Replace with: `$1\L$3\E\U$4\E$5`
- Check *Match case*
- Check *Wrap around*
- Select *Regular expression*
- Uncheck *. matches newline*
- Press *Replace All*

Here's a GIF of this in action:

[image]

The breakdown of the *Find what* field:

- `^` at the front of the Regular Expression represents the beginning of a line and `$` at the end represents the end of a line. This prevents it from being lazy or wrapping to the next line.
- `([^:]+:)` represents the characters at the beginning of the line, allowing all characters except `:`. This is group `$1`
- `(([A-Z])|([a-z]))` represents the first character after the `:`. If there is anything other than an upper or lowercase letter, it will skip the line.

  - Group `$2` will be the first character, regardless of uppercase or lowercase. We'll ignore this in our replacement.
  - Group `$3` will be the first character if it is uppercase, otherwise `$3` will be empty.
  - Group `$4` will be the first character if it is lowercase, otherwise `$4` will be empty.
- `([^:]+)` represents the characters at the end of the line, allowing all characters except `:`. This is group `$5`.

The breakdown of the *Replace with* field:

- `$1` will be the first group as described above
- `\L$3\E` will convert group `$3` as described above to lowercase.
- `\U$4\E' will convert group`$4` as described above to uppercase.
- `$5` will be the last group as described above

`\L` and `\U` stand for "beginning converting to lowercase" or "uppercase," respectively. `\E` stands for "stop converting." Since only one out of `$3` or `$4` will contain the first character (the other will be blank), this converts only in the case we want.

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution first. It did the trick! Thanks alot for the explanation too

Answer (score 6):

**This is the simplest solution I could come up with.**

Find what: `:(\u)|:(\l)`

Replace with: `:\l($1)\u($2)`

Enable the settings: Wrap Around & Match case

Search mode: Regular expression

Press Replace All.

#### Explanation

`\u matches & converts uppercase, \l matches & converts lowercase.`

[image]

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of `\u,\l` for matching.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried your answer too. Also does the trick, thanks :)

Comment: @Toto it is Notepad++ specific regex. `\u` is a shorthand for `[A-Z]` and `\l` = `[a-z]`. So in other software one can just replace with that.

Comment: with your answer solved my problem easily, i had to lowercase after \n so I first replaced \n with % (I don't use % in my text) then used your example, then changed by % to \n... :D